# php html select box, insert variable day/days

Tags: php, html, variables, select

i have the following code to get the options from the database, but right now it shows as:
1 - eur 17.50 . i would like to put the word day (for 1 day) or days (if value is more than 1) in this text so it would show up as this: 1 day - EUR 17.50   or  6 days - EUR 80. How to achieve this?

```
<form method="post" action="framemaat.php?lang=<?=$_SESSION['lang'];?>&naam=<?=$naam;?>&postcodehuisnummer=<?=$postcodehuisnummer;?>&fietskeuze=<?=$fietskeuze;?>&opties=<?=$opties;?>&optieid=<?=$optieid;?>">
        <h2><?=$lang['pagina3_dagen']?> <select id="dagen" name="dagen" style="width:75;" style="height:250px;">
            <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM $tabel WHERE fietstype='$fietskeuze'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Ophalen prijzen mislukt: ".mysql_error());

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $dagen=$row[dagen];
            $prijs=$row[prijs];
                echo "<option>
                    $dagen - EUR: $prijs    
                </option>";
            }  
            ?> 
        </select>

        <input type="submit" name="Submit" value="Volgende">
</form>
```

Comment: Where do you define the second price?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should be pretty simple.

```
 <?php
            $query="SELECT * FROM $tabel WHERE fietstype='$fietskeuze'";
            $result=mysql_query($query) or die ("Ophalen prijzen mislukt: ".mysql_error());

            while ($row=mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
            $dagen=$row[dagen];
            if($dagen>1){
               $dayString = " days";
               }else{
               $dayString = " day";
               }
            $prijs=$row[prijs];
                echo "<option>
                    $dagen $dayString - EUR: $prijs    
                </option>";
            }  
            ?>
```

Comment: oh man, i was trying too hard :) thanks, got i working as it should now! i'll accept the answer in a few minutes